# retrieving content from parse.com into RecyclerView.adapter

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I am building an application integrated with parse. I have a recycler view integrated in my app where I have to fetch data from the Parse database.
I am not able to find any information about how to do it. Would like if someone can give an insight on how to fetch data on my RecyclerView Adapter from Parse database?

I have to fetch that data and pass it to the recycler view adapter so that the info can be set on the textview in the recyclerView.

Comment: Please post your code.